# Looping over URLs in Casperjs

Tags: coffeescript, casperjs

I'm trying to open a couple of URLs in sequence with Casperjs.

Here is a simplified version of my actual code.

```
casper = require('casper').create()
casper.start()

casper.then () ->
  items = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com']

  for item, idx in items
     this.open item
     this.then ((idx) ->
        () ->
            this.capture idx + '.png')(idx)

casper.run()
```

In my actual code, the items array is generated at runtime. I expect that this code will provide screenshots of google.com and yahoo.com, but actually both screen shots end up as yahoo.com. I feel like this has something to do with creating a closure inside a loop, but I can't see how. When `open` is called, `item` refers to a specific string. I'm never closing over it, am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`casper.open`](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/bed988a8e9bb758a590a8333f42c8cbd62718c4d/modules/casper.js#L1395) doesn't add a step, so it is not asynchronous (like `thenOpen`). It is immediately executed inside of the outer `then`. But the following `then` *is* asynchronous so its step is added to be executed after the current step (outer `then`). Both `open`s are executed, but the callbacks of both `then`s are executed after the last `open`.

So the solution would be to use `thenOpen` as a combined asynchronous step. There is a slight problem with the straigt forward solution:

> [CoffeeScript is a little language that compiles into JavaScript.](http://coffeescript.org)

Which means that JavaScript misconceptions apply. This is the one: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

The `for item, idx in items` line is still a [for loop in JavaScript](http://coffeescript.org/#loops). JavaScript has function level scope and `casper.then` is an asynchronous step function which means that the callbacks of all the `casper.then` calls are executed after the loop has run completely through (more precisely after the current step is finished or after `casper.run` was called), but `casper.open` is immediately executed.

Solution: Combine `casper.open` and `casper.then` to `casper.thenOpen` and pass `item` and `idx` through an IIFE so that they are fixed to each iteration:

```
for item, idx in items
    ((item, idx) ->
        casper.thenOpen item, () ->
            this.capture idx + '.png'
    )(item, idx)
```

or use `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
items.forEach (item, idx) ->
    casper.thenOpen item, () ->
        this.capture idx + '.png'
```

Comment: I'm not that fluent in coffeescript, so I don't know for sure if the above code is syntactically correct.

Comment: Doesn't `casper.open` add the open page command to the stack of steps? The actual opening of the page happens after `casper.run`  called as well so why would there be a sequencing issue? The reason I put the `idx` inside a closure was as you say, because I want the specific index to be preserved at runtime. But why would a closure be needed for the `casper.open` call? Your idea of bundling them together worked but I hope you understand why I'm still a little confused. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I thought that was not that clear on my part. I hope it is better now.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. In my mind I translate `casper.open(string)` and `casper.then(func)` to `someQueue.push(["open", string])` and `someQueue.push(["then", func])`. I see why, in the second case, evaluation of the `func` may fail if the names that it closes over have changed, but why would the value of `["open", string]` ever be changed? It's just an array of strings.

Comment: "`someQueue.push(["open", string])`" doesn't happen, because `casper.open` is not a step function. It is immediately executed, but "`someQueue.push(["then", func])`" does happen and it is executed after the second `casper.open`. So both screenshots show the same page.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. I must have a fundamental misunderstanding somewhere. How could `open` be immediately executed if execution occurs when `casper.run` is called? Surely `run` must look inside some table to find an `open` command saved.

Comment: `open` is immediately executed when it is called, but it is only called inside of the outer `then`. It might help if you look into the source code.